# Combining dataframes so that column entries in left side equal column entries in right side and if not return null

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

so I have two data frames to start with in pandas.

One data frame has more columns than the other
In the larger one, some of those columns contain identical rows as those in the smaller frame.

I want to combine the two data frames so that the rows in both frames that are equal result in one row, and the rows that are NOT equal lead to a null.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: dataframe1]

[image: dataframe2]

[image: resulting_data_frame]

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 3, 'alpha'], [2, 4, 'beta']], columns=['a', 'b', 'features'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [1, 3]], columns=['u', 'v'])
```

How could this be done in pandas? How about in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

use `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['a', 'b'], right_on=['u', 'v'], how='left')
```

It basically is a left join

Comment: Nice answer (-:

Comment: Here is great post regarding this type of operation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html